# SELECTing SUM Across Two Tables for Each User

Tags: mysql, math, join, sum

I have an application with a users table, credit_purchase table, and credit_spend table. I am trying to get the amount of credits the user currently has.

The credit tables are as follows:

credit_purchase

```
+----+---------+-------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | coins | timestamp           |
+----+---------+-------+---------------------+
```

credit_spend

```
+----+---------+-------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | coins | timestamp           |
+----+---------+-------+---------------------+
```

What I'm trying to do is select the SUM(credit_purchase.coins) - SUM(credit_spend.coins) for each user. Right now I have something like this:

```
SELECT users.*, COALESCE(SUM(credit_purchase.coins) - SUM(credit_spend.coins), 0) 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN credit_purchase ON users.id = credit_purchase.user_id 
LEFT JOIN credit_spend ON users.id = credit_spend.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id
```

but, it the result is not the correct number. It seems to be SUMing the purchases properly, but multiplying the SUM from the spend by the number of purchases.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT  users.*, 
        COALESCE(SUM(credit_purchase.coins) - SUM(credit_spend.coins), 0) 
FROM    users 
            LEFT JOIN credit_purchase
                    ON users.id = credit_purchase.user_id 
            LEFT JOIN credit_spend 
                    ON users.id = credit_spend.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: Oops. I wrote the question with the wrong table name. The edit reflects what I've been using for the application.